# How much electricity does a thermostat consume?

Tags: electrical, heat

I live in a condo and the heat is supplied by a gas furnace located in the building. Heat is included in my condo fee but I'm wondering if turning on the thermostat uses any electricity and how much?

Comment: 99.9% of thermostats will get their power from the furnace itself. In the unlikely case where it doesn't, a normal thermostat draws so little power that it won't make any difference to you.

Answer (score 2):

Most thermostats use very little power, if any. Many of the Honeywell programmable thermostats you can buy from retail places, for instance, [take 2 AA batteries for their power source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsAE_GoejKY) and do NOT pull power from the fan unit. If your unit is a WiFi one, that may not be as true.

Either way, I'd be surprised to see one consume more than a dollar a month at most.

Comment: 2 AA batteries can supply up to around .0075 kWh, so in my market that comes out to roughly 65 cents assuming that that batteries drain every month (they don't).  Probably closer to 1-2 cents a month based on how often I replace them.

Comment: .0075 kWh in my market @ $0.09 per kWh is about 0.065 cents; not even 1/10 of a penny.  For 0.0075 kWh to be $0.65 would be $86.66/kWh which would be a bit outrageous.

Comment: Why my electricity bill is much higher when the heat is on? (Heat is included in my condo fee)

Comment: Not sure. Depends a lot on what kind of heat they're using. Should ask it in another question